# Scale and nested meshes

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm trying to display a set of nested meshes which I retrieve from a server and cannot change. The meshes are a bit unusual in so far that the rotations and positions are in local co-ordinates but the scalings are all in global co-ordinates.

Ideally I would prefer to maintain the hierarchy by adding the child meshes to the THREE.Mesh but a solution where the hierarchy is flattened would be workable too.

My problem is that simply adding the child meshes makes the size of the child meshes explode:

```
this.add(child);
```

will make the volume of the child and the child's child too large because the server assumes that scaling information is not inherited.

I have tried a simple:

```
child.scale.divide(this.scale);
this.add(child);
```

but that doesn't work, I assume this is because `THREE.Object3D`'s `matrix` is defined as [Rotation x Scale x Translation].

My liniear algebra is a bit rusty, can somebody give me a few pointers on how to adjust the scaling vector of the children?

Comment: 1. If all the objects are added to the scene directly, do they visually look correct in position, rotation, and scale? 2. Do you want to create a parent `Object3D`, add the objects as children and grandchildren of the parent, and have it appear as in (1)?

Comment: If I add the objects directly to the scene then they do not appear in the correct postion (typically close to 0,0,0 in world co-ordinates). If I add the position of the parent object prior to adding the child directly to the scene, then the rotations are off. I can - mostly - correct the rotations by multiplying the position with the parents quaternion prior to adding the child object. By "mostly" I mean that all but a few objects appear in the scene with the correct position and rotation using that method. Ideally I would like to have one Object3D with children and grandchildren.

Comment: 1. If you add the objects in the proper heierarchical order, is the position and rotation correct -- and only the scale wrong? 2. If so, then set the scale to ( 1, 1, 1 ), and scale up the geometry of each object to its correct global size by using `geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( s, s, s ) )`.

Comment: Yes, that did do the trick :-), and hardly without any use of my rusty linear algebra. Thanks. I can easily live with the vertices being scaled rather than using the scale property, I prefer that much to not having a proper hierarchy to rely on when doing rotations and translations.

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the objects in the proper hierarchical order, set the scale to ( 1, 1, 1 ), and scale up the geometry of each object to its correct global size by using:

```
geometry.scale( s, s, s );
```

three.js r.86

Comment: isn't this exactly the same as `geometry.scale(s, s, s)` ?

Comment: @pinkli Yes. That method was added later. Updated answer. Thanks!